# Readjust auto_increment primary key field after deletion of a row

Tags: mysql

I've following table configuration

```
CREATE TABLE Verses
(
ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
verse_title varchar(255),
verse_desc varchar(255)
)
```

I want to keep id of all rows contiguously, and it is okay until I delete some rows. after I deleted a row (say Id=2), I want to insert new insertion with id=2. please see attatched image.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alter table AUTO_INCREMENT

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = your_value
```

You can obtain the actual value for autoincremnt in this way  ..

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'your_table';
```

then you can use the alter table ..

or you can select the count() of the rows after deleteing your row and the sue the alter tbale  ..

Comment: Yeah this works when we manually know which value is deleted, Actually, i am asking if there is any mechanism to define while creating table, which needs to work even if more than one data is removed.